# What is wrong with my code that creates a static data member?

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, g++, ld

I am just coding various scenarios for `static`, `const` and `global` variables, to see where they work and where they don't.

Following code is giving me weird `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
const static int gl = 4;
class Static{
    private:
            int nonStatic;
            const static int count = 10;
            //constexpr static string str;
            static vector<string> svec;
    public:
            static vector<string> initVector();
            void printVector();
            Static(int s=0): nonStatic(s){}
            ~Static(){}

};

vector<string> Static::initVector()
{
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
            string str;
            cin>>str;
            svec.push_back(str);
    }
}

void Static::printVector()
{
    for(auto const i: svec)
            cout<<i;
}

int main()
{
    Static state(4);
    return 0;
}
```

It shows the following `ld` error message:

```
/tmp/ccsX2Fre.o: In function `Static::initVector[abi:cxx11]()':
StaticTests.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `Static::svec[abi:cxx11]'
/tmp/ccsX2Fre.o: In function `Static::printVector()':
StaticTests.cpp:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `Static::svec[abi:cxx11]'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site might be a better fit for this.

Comment: Code review is for working code.

Comment: You need to define  `svec`.

Comment: Also `Static::initVector()` should return something but it does not.

Comment: you should avoid naming your class with keywords. I was confused when reading the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static std::vector<std::string> svec;` **declares** a static object named `svec` of type `std::vector<std::string>`. You have to **define** it as well. After the definition of `Static` add the definition:

```
std::vector<std::string> Static::svec;
```

And to answer the next question, the declaration of `count` is also a definition because it has an initializer. As long as you don't take its address you don't need a separate definition.

Comment: note that "Static::" is the class-name.